# JSON.parse throwing illogical Syntax Error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a problem with parsing the json string passed from a method in PHP over an AJAX call.
The string is

```
[{"type":"successful","message":"Prijava uspe\u0161na!"}]
```

When I try to parse it in javascript with `JSON.parse(the string)`, I get an Unexpected token error in my console.

There is no problem when I execute this on my localhost nothing is wrong even though I get the same response from the PHP script.

When I try the following in the success function of the ajax

```
console.log(message);
console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
console.log(JSON.parse(message));
```

I get this

```
[{"type":"successful","message":"Prijava uspe\u0161na!"}]  login:102
"\r\n\r\n[{\"type\":\"successful\",\"message\":\"Prijava uspe\\u0161na!\"}]\r\n\r\n" login:104
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  login:104
```

And line 104 (well not really, the console points at it):

```
console.log(JSON.parse(message));
```

I've tried replacing \r\n, ended up the same

I am really confused...

Comment: Your JSON parses fine.  `JSON.parse('[{"type":"successful","message":"Prijava uspe\\u0161na!"}] ');`

Comment: maybe he passed the object instead of the string (without the quotes)

Comment: @Brad Yes I am aware of that, but it does not when it's passed from a php echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON has a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which is not a valid token.

Ensure that whatever is sending your JSON is encoding it correctly without this BOM.

Comment: Could you please explain? The PHP method echos the array with json_encode

Comment: If your PHP script is encoded as UTF-8 with BOM, then the BOM is output. Encode your PHP script as either ANSI (a single-byte character set) or UTF-8 *without* BOM.

Comment: Hehe, one thing you learn to recognise is "invisible errors" :D