# 'Unexpected token' when using JSON.parse from array made in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I'm trying to AJAX a JSON array but for some reason when I use JSON.parse it gives me the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Here is my PHP:

```
$infoJson = array('info' => array());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    array_push($infoJson['info'],
    [
        'section' => $row['section'],
        'source' => $row['source'],
        'project' => $row['project'],
        'client' => $row['client'],
        'date' => $row['date'],
        'id' => $row['id']
    ]);
}
echo json_encode($infoJson);
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
    {
        var response = request.responseText;
        response = JSON.parse(response);
    }
}
request.open('GET','http:edit.php?requestedArray=printArray',true);
request.send();
```

Also here is exactly what the PHP is echoing:

```
{"info":[{"section":"printArray","source":"http:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/commons\/thumb\/7\/7a\/SNES-Controller.jpg\/1280px-SNES-Controller.jpg","project":"SNES","client":"Nintendo","date":"1990","id":"7"},{"section":"printArray","source":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/81Q0l1t%2BaJL._SL1500_.jpg","project":"Playstation","client":"Sony","date":"1994","id":"8"},{"section":"printArray","source":"http:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/commons\/e\/ed\/Xbox-360-S-Controller.png","project":"Xbox 360","client":"Microsoft","date":"2005","id":"9"}]}
```

If I don't use JSON.parse and console.log response, I do receive it as a string.

Comment: Are you using jQuery at all, I usually just do $.post, you could try sending header('Content-Type: application/json'); but I'm not sure if that would have any effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON.parse throwing illogical Syntax Error: Unexpected token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942498/json-parse-throwing-illogical-syntax-error-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output parses fine, except for the invalid, invisible character `'\ufeff'` at the beginning of the string. This is the [UTF-16 byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16). You are probably sending the string with an incorrect/missing `charset` in your `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Just out of curiosity how do you tell that?

Comment: Triple-click the text in the question, paste it into the JavaScript console: `var s = '<paste>'; s.charCodeAt(0); /* 65279 */ JSON.parse(s); /* Unexpected token */ JSON.parse(s.substr(1));  /* Object { info: Array[3] }  */`

Comment: Whats the fix ?