# Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

**[SOLUTION]** Saving the relevant .php files in ANSI solved this issue. Check the accepted answer for more information.

I get this error in console when trying to parse JSON coming from PHP's `json_encode()`:

```
VM2538:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (products.js:169)
at i (jquery-v3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-v3.2.1.min.js:2)
at A (jquery-v3.2.1.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-v3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

I tried setting MySql's server and tables collation to utf8_unicode_ci as suggested in some answers but that made no difference.
Also added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` to HTML head and `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` to PHP file, which changed the output of `json_encode()` a bit. (Both examples included at the bottom)

**[UPDATED]** Here's the JavaScript:
(atm I just wanna log a value to the console, so success function is not complete)

```
function loadProducts() {
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'ajax/list_products.php',
  success: function(products) {
    var json = products;
    console.log(json);
    console.log(json[0].Code);
    console.log(json[0]["Code"]);
  }
});
```

}

This is the PHP code from `list_products.php`:

```
<?php
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once $root . "/commander/class/product.php";

$product = new Product();
$productList = $product->listProducts();

if (!empty($productList) > 0) {
  echo json_encode($productList);
}else {
  echo "Error - Records are empty.";
}
```

And this is the output from `list_products.php` without `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/0AeqTtmd)

With `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`:
[PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/SEa4m6GK)

Comment: You're already returning parsed json, log out `products` without parsing it

Comment: Your else statement does not `echo` a json string

Comment: `console.log(products[0].Code);` and `console.log(products[0]["Code"]);` both return `undefined`

Comment: JSON is echoed correctly, check the pastebins, that's the output

Comment: Remove the Content-Type header and use `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax setup.  You shouldn't need to use JSON.parse after that.

Comment: Added `dataType: 'json',` to ajax, console now doesn't output anything at all.

Comment: Can you show the code? Doesn't output anything when you do what?

Comment: I'll add the updated code to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing or invalid headers can cause the response to come in an unexpected format leaving it with an invisible '\ufeff' token at the beginning. This is used to state the endianness of the message received and make it readable to any receiver (but difficult to consume inside an application).

In cases where you are the sender, you will want to adjust your headers to have the correct charset and content type.

In cases where you are the receiver, you can turn the response into valid JSON by removing the first character and calling JSON.parse (or your language's equivalent) on the body.

For more info, see this question, answer, and wiki:

['Unexpected token' when using JSON.parse from array made in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708187/unexpected-token-when-using-json-parse-from-array-made-in-php)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16

Comment: Thanks, the wiki link led me to discover a common problem with this BOM thing, fixed the issue by saving the php files in ANSI even though I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.